# Bootstrap tabs don't work with Firebug

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, firebug, twitter-bootstrap-2

Here's a small jQuery test program using Bootstrap 2.0 tabs. The peculiar thing is that if you run this in Firefox, it works just as expected. Though if you turn on Firebug, the tabs stop working! Is there some event handling that I'm missing? As you can imagine, it's making debugging my project very very challenging!

(If you want to run this - copy the file to your web root and modify the paths to the jQuery and Bootstrap files - it's an example I found on JSFiddle. Then, in Firefox access the HTML file.)

tab-test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="./bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/assets/js/holder.js"></script>
<link href="./bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#myTab a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret">    </b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#dropdown1">Dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#dropdown2">Dropdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>Section A</h3>
        <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel,  butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Section B</h3>
        <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 1</h3>
        <p>WInteger convallis, nulla in sollicitudin placerat, ligula enim auctor lectus, in mollis diam dolor at lorem. Sed bibendum nibh sit amet dictum feugiat. Vivamus arcu sem, cursus a feugiat ut, iaculis at erat. Donec vehicula at ligula vitae venenatis. Sed nunc nulla, vehicula non porttitor in, pharetra et dolor. Fusce nec velit velit. Pellentesque consectetur eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdown2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Dropdown 2</h3>
            <p>Donec vel placerat quam, ut euismod risus. Sed a mi suscipit, elementum sem a, hendrerit velit. Donec at erat magna. Sed dignissim orci nec eleifend egestas. Donec eget mi consequat massa vestibulum laoreet. Mauris et ultrices nulla, malesuada volutpat ante. Fusce ut orci lorem. Donec molestie libero in tempus imperdiet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try detaching the firebug from firefox.

Comment: Works fine for me using Firefox 33.0.1 + Firebug 2.0.4 on Win7 (fetching the JS and CSS files from CDNs). Which versions of Firefox and Firebug do you use?

Comment: I'm on FF 33.0 and Firebug 2.0.4 on Mac....hmmmmm. Let me try @Cerlin's suggestion of detaching firebug.

Comment: I tried both detaching Firebug and also using the JS & CSS files from CDNs (instead of my local copy) - but no dice. It seems as though the event to switch tabs doesn't take. When I mouse over the other tabs, it clearly sees the html...aaargh. What else can I try? The only difference between my case and @Sebastian's is Win/Mac.

Comment: The Firebug wiki has some info on [how to isolate the problem](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/I_found_a_Firebug_Bug!#Isolating_the_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the Firebug wiki pointer. When I tried this out with FireFox 32.0.3 and Firebug 2.0.4 everything worked. I will keep investigating.

Answer (score 0):

No need of calling tabs explicitly in JavaScript. It works with Bootstrap by default.
It works for me without the JavaScript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTab a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. On each tab selection I need to do something else - though in the test program I just display the content. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I have copied your code in my local and removed the Javascript code from it. It worked for me with the firebug open also.

Comment: Quick question - are you on a Mac ?

Comment: No, i am on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Mac, using OS X Snow Leopard 10.8.5 (old I know, but a work computer that needs to work), Firefox 33.1, Firebug 2.0.6 and having the same problem:  After freshly starting firefox, bootstrap tabs work fine until I open firebug, then they stop working.  I have to restart the browser to get the tabs working again.

Everything was working fine (with exactly the same version of bootstrap), until a recent firefox update (not sure which one).

Frustrating.

:wq

Comment: I did more investigation after my original post. It does seem to be Mac specific. I went back to Firefox 32.0.3 and the problem went away. I did try it again on FF 33.1.0 and it continued to have problems. I have not yet checked out 33.1.1 yet. So go back to FF 32.0.3 and Firebug will work again for you.

Comment: Fantastic thank you.  Downgrading to 32.0.3 has sorted the issue for me too.

Comment: I upgraded to Yosemite on MacOS and now with Firefox 36.0 and Firebug 2.0.8 I am able to debug with Bootstrap tabs.

Comment: One more thing - if after upgrade it does not work, delete Firefox from your system and reinstall. It works then. There is some setting or stored data that seems to get in the way after upgrade. Hope this helps.